# grab image from clipbroad fuction pyhon in linux

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am looking for a method in which I can grab the image which is on the clipboard and assign it to the background of a pygame screen. I am trying to make an app in which a user can quickly annotate a captured image in linux. Below is a an example of what I am talking about. Unfortunately these modules do not work in linux. It's not the complete code and I have just included it to make my question clearer.

```
import pygame

from PIL import ImageTk, ImageGr

pygame.init()

def backgroundimage():
   while True:
        clipimage = ImageGrab.grabclipboard() 
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(([800,800]), pygame.NOFRAME)
        screen.fill((clipimage))

if __name__ == '__main__':
     backgroundimage()
```